# Prove these functions are linear or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I go about finding out if these functions are linear because it is in $\mathbb R^3$ and also in $\mathbb R^2 $.

$ T: \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R $ with $T(x,y,z)=(x+y+z+1).$
and this question too. $T: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ with $T(x,y,z)=(2x-y+z,x-2zy)$

Comment: Do you know the definition of a linear transformation @user7112108?

Comment: The second map is not $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$

Comment: Can you please explain why is it not?

Comment: the RHS is not an ordered triple, you need to specify the third component

Answer (score 1):

For your first $T$, note that $T(0, 0, 0) = 1 \ne 0$. A linear map takes $0$ to $0$.

For your second $T$, something is missing (the second vector is in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$), but anyway you should know that the components of a linear map must be zero, or homogeneous polynomials of total degree $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is linear if it preserves the following proprieties:

$T(a + b) = T(a) + T(b)$

$T(k*a) = k*T(a),$ where k is constant

And the combination of these as well:

$T(k*a + b) = k*T(a) + T(b)$

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, try a special case to see why this $+1$ operation does not work:

If, $T :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, where $T(x)= x+1$, then $T(x+y)=x+y+1 \neq (x+1)+(y+1)= T(x)+T(y)$.

Your case is the same, take two vectors $v,w \in \mathbb R^3$ and check to see that the same problem arises.

Assuming that you meant $\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2$ , $T(x,y,z)=(2x−y+z,x−2zy) $ may be linear. Check to see if scalar multiplication "works:"

$\begin{align*}\alpha \cdot  T(x,y,z)&=\alpha \cdot (2x−y+z,x−2zy) \\
&=\big(2(\alpha )-\alpha y, \alpha x-2 (\alpha xy)\big) \\
&\neq 2\big(\alpha )-\alpha y, \alpha x-2 (\alpha x)(\alpha y)\big) \\
&= T(\alpha x,\alpha y, \alpha z).\end{align*}$

The not equals holds unless $\alpha=\alpha^2$.